Magento 2 : How to avoid discount to custom option
We are using magento 2.4.2-p2
When we apply a coupon code to the cart then the discount is also applied to the product custom options, we do not want to apply a discount to the product custom options.
Example -
1 - Without custom options(which is fine)
Product price - 315
Product price with tax - 47.25
Order Total - 362.25
After applied discount - 15%
TOTAL
Subtotal  SAR 315.00
Discount (etet)   - SAR 47.25(here - 315−15%=267.75, 315-267.75=47.25)
Tax   SAR 40.16(here discount is applying - 47.25−15%=40.16)
Order Total   SAR 307.91
2 - With custom options(don't want to add discount on custom options)
Product price - 315
Custom option price - 70
Custom option price with tax(15%) - 80.50
Product price with tax - 57.75
Order Total - 442.75
After applied discount - 15%
TOTAL
Subtotal  SAR 385.00(315+70)
Discount (etet)   - SAR 57.75(385−15%=327.25, 385-327.25=57.75)
Tax   SAR 49.09(here - 57.75−15%=49.09)
Order Total   SAR 376.34
Here -
Tax - 15%
Discount - 15%

can you please share the more detail. Because discount of cart price rule. It will always apply on the product final price. And using custom option your
Final price = product main price+custom option price.

@KarangarMeghnathi i updated my questions

It seems like you already the some customization to add custom option price in total ? you will need to enhance that module and refactor possibly add custom price and tax after tax/discount rules etc are calculated. I don't get the full requirement by what you have shared.
